# Multiple JAXRS Bean with one Jetty Endpoint

Tags: jetty, jax-rs, apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

can anybody help me with the configuration of two JAX-RS Services with the same Base URI with Apache FUSE ESB ? I'm using the JBoss FUSE 6.0 release with the karaf container, Apache Camel and CXF (JAX-RS). The configuration is done with Blueprint. Everything is working fine when I only configure one JAX-RS Service.

I'm trying to serve two JAX-RS Beans with the base URI `http://localhost:9001/rs`. With the first bean as `http://localhost:9001/rs/rest1` and the second with `http://locahost:9001/rs/rest2`.

I have defined two camel contexts with the jetty endpoints. I think i need two use only one configured instance, but cannot figure it out how to do this.

Here are my Camel Contexts:

```
<camel:camelContext id="context1">
    <camel:endpoint id="ep1" uri="jetty:http://localhost:9001/rs/?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
    <camel:route autoStartup="true">
        <camel:from uri="ep1"/>
        <camel:to uri="cxfbean:restBean1"/>
        <camel:log message="Message received after REST Processor. "/>
        <camel:convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
        <camel:to uri="log:loggingCategory?level=INFO"/>
    </camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>

<camel:camelContext id="context2">
    <camel:endpoint id="ep2" uri="jetty:http://localhost:9001/rs/?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
    <camel:route autoStartup="true">
        <camel:from uri="ep2"/>
        <camel:to uri="cxfbean:restBean2"/>
        <camel:log message="Message received after REST Processor. "/>
        <camel:convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
        <camel:to uri="log:loggingCategory?level=INFO"/>
    </camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>
```

Both Beans are injected as a Service Reference and everything works when i comment one of the routes.

Any suggestions how to configure this in camel ?

Cheers, 
Oliver

Answer (score 1):

The 2 jetty endpoints should be unique, eg you have both with /rs/
It should likely be

```
 <camel:endpoint id="ep1" uri="jetty:http://localhost:9001/rs/rest1/?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>

 <camel:endpoint id="ep2" uri="jetty:http://localhost:9001/rs/rest2/?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
```

Comment: Hi. i think the workaround to make this work will be two Endpoints with the path of the bean included and to set the Bean Path to "/". This works for my setup.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the issue with two endpoints

```
<camel:endpoint id="ep1" uri="jetty:http://localhost:9001/rs/rest1/?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
<camel:endpoint id="ep2" uri="jetty:http://localhost:9001/rs/rest2/?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
```

The REST Beans are now with `@Path("/")`.
Now all REST Beans have the correct pathes.

The next thing i need to test is how to get my two endpoints together with my web app bundle on the same URL.

Thanks !